# Load more <div> on scroll before bottom

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, scroll

Hey im looking for a simple jquery script that loads more content or divs when user scrolls down.

I checked the infinite scroll plugin but it seems to only work with next page.

I have no next page function for my pages so all my (content) divs are loaded at once.

Im looking for a script that can load a certain amount of divs each time the user scrolls to bottom just like Facebook has implemented.

FYI im on wordpress. http://img.studio-heads.net/

Answer (score 1):

I have a very simple way to do this without needing a plugin, just add the code below:

```
if ($("#div").scrollTop() +  $("#div").innerHeight()  >  this.scrollHeight - 100 ) {
       // you need change value 100 according your situation
       $("#div").append();  // your loading more code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always just change your WordPress theme to apply your own Infinite Scroll to work the way you want it to?

For example: http://www.infinite-scroll.com/
They pretty much tell you how to set it up for your content

Another is http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/
This one, when you apply it, works with your content to load pages as you go down the page, turning your existing pagination into an infinite scrolling one.

The documentation on them apply to whatyou're looking for, I believe.